# Boot error for newly compiled kernel in Ubuntu

Tags: boot, kernel

When I am booting into the newly compiled kernel it is showing error. Following image shows where the booting stopped.

[image]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What version of the kernel are you attempting to compile and run? Please help us help you!

Comment: It's clear you can't mount the root file system. This is a large part if not the whole problem.

Comment: Goldfish? It sounds like you have compiled an Android configuration. Have you built an initramfs? What instructions have you followed?